# How to get a child key name randomly from the Firebase Realtime database with a Javascript cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to randomly get a child key from the pickers section and then add data to it from another node. I want to do all of this with a JavaScript Cloud Function. Here is my code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onDataAdded = functions.database.ref('/Pickup-Requests/{uid}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const getRandomPickerid =    
        database.ref('/Pickers').once('value').then(event => {
        const pickerUid =  Object.keys()[random];
        return pickerUid;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error", error);

    });

    const pickerUid = getRandomPickerid;

    const data = snapshot.val();
    const newData = data;
    return snapshot.ref.parent.child(pickerUid).set(newData);

});
```

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Which error do you encounter with your code?

Comment: Database.ref not defined

Comment: You don't define `database` anywhere (based on the code in your question). You should use the Admin SDK as follows: `const database = admin.database()`

Comment: Also, where do you declare/initialize `random`?

Comment: For the Pickers node

Comment: Do you mean that there is a node with a property `random` somewhere in your Realtime Database?? can you add a screenshot of the detail of a Picker?

Comment: No, I want to randomly choose between 1 of the picker among the node(Pickers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

function randomKey(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return keys[(keys.length * Math.random()) << 0];
}

exports.onDataAdded = functions.database.ref('/Pickup-Requests/{uid}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const db = admin.database();
    const data = snapshot.val();

    return db.ref('/Pickers').once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
        const pickerUid = randomKey(snapshot.val()); 
        return snapshot.ref.parent.child(pickerUid).set(data);
    })

});
```

---

I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: It's not working, the new data is being attached on the root and its key name is node_. Also, the logs are showing me that the billing account is not configured. Do I need to upgrade my plan for it to work?
Database image
https://ibb.co/cDNy8GS
Logs image
https://ibb.co/p1bzXMx

Comment: I had to adapt the answer, from `randomKey(snapshot);` to `randomKey(snapshot.val());`.  The message you get is just an info message: in your case you don't need to upgrade, unless you plan to go over the free tier limits.

Comment: Ok, so I will have to upgrade it if I want to scale up my project. Thanks a lot.